# External libraries in a WordPress plugin

Tags: plugins, library

I tried to find an answer to this; also searched some well known plugins, but the ones that use external libraries distribute them in the folder `/vendor` because of the usage of composer.

So, what is the most appropriate/sensible folder to place external libraries that you need to simply `include()` in your plugin? Say, a library like [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord)...

Thanks in advance for your thoughts.

Comment: It's up to you. Something like `lib` or `includes` is how I'd do it, but this is your code, not mine.

Comment: As I said, I was expecting your thoughts! I know it's up to me at the end. Anyway, so I ended up using `/libraries` directly under my plugin's folder.

Comment: This is more of an opinion-based question as there's no real right answer here :/ at the end of the day it's just how you choose to set up your folder structure, basically anything would work, as long as you understand what it means.